# Como establecer la fecha actual por default en calendario con javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, datepicker

Tengo estos dos campos de tipo fecha, que los utilizo para establecer un periodo de fechas

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input id="fechInicio"  name="fechInicio" class="form-control" type="text"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
  <input id="fechFin"  name="fechFin" class="form-control" type="text"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que en el datetimepicker2 al cargar la pagina por default tenga la fecha del día actual y que NO se pueda seleccionar la fecha de un día después del día actual, y que en el datetimepicker1  solo se puedan escoger fechas de un bimestre hacia atrás de la fecha actual.

Como puedo hacer eso?

Solo tengo este código que inicializa

```html
function validaFechas(){

 $('datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      locale: 'es',
   format: 'L',
   useCurrent: true,
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  
 });
 
 $('datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      locale: 'es',
   format: 'L',
   useCurrent: true,
   format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
 });
    $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change",function (e){
      var fechaInicio = new Date(e.date);
      $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
      var maximaFechaFin = new Date();
      maximaFechaFin.setMinutes(1);
      $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(maximaFechaFin);
      });
 
      $("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change",function (e)
      {
       
      $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
      var maximaFechaInicio = new Date();
      var minimoFechaInicio = new Date(maximaFechaInicio.getFullYear(), 
      maximaFechaInicio.getMonth(), maximaFechaInicio.getDate() -92);
      
    $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(minimoFechaInicio);
      });
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
$( "#datetimepicker2" ).datepicker({
  maxDate:'today',
  minDate: '-2m'
});
$( "#datetimepicker2" ).datepicker( "setDate", "today" );
```

Con esto debería funcionarte.

Saludos

Comment: Ya lo implemente pero al cargar la página no aparece por default la fecha y si le doy click no se despliega el calendario, no hace nada

Comment: estas usando el DatePicker de JQuery ? o cual estas usando?

Comment: @ Alejandro Gonzalez, si, tengo este código que si le doy click en un calendario en automático me pone la fecha actual en ambos, pero no se como hacer que ya por default esten cargados cuando entre a la pagina

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta con mi código actual

Answer (score 0):

si es para poner la fecha default a penas carga la pagina puedes utilizar jquery y ejecutar el codigo que respondio alejandro a penas el DOM este cargado y listo.

```
$(function(){

    $( "#datetimepicker2" ).datepicker({
      maxDate:'today',
      minDate: '-2m'
    });

    $( "#datetimepicker2" ).datepicker( "setDate", "today" );

});
```